# CALL pointing out of memory range - assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, qemu

I'm debugging with qemu and GDB a bootloader in x86 that makes something interesting.

I have launched my qemu with -m 1024k, because the code doesent need more memory, and I observed that the codes have some CALL like this:

`call 0x5727ce6`

That it is poitning out of memory, there is only 0x100000 bytes of memory. The program do not crash, it execute 00 intstructions that GDB interpretate as:

`ADD byte PTR [EAX],AL`

During a while, and next, it resumes the execution like a RETURN, but without it.

Comment: Are you in protected mode already? Note that gdb isn't terribly good with real mode. You might be disassembling 16 bit code as 32 bit.

Comment: Regions of physical address space not backed by actual RAM might just fetch as `00`.  Or qemu might trap them.  IDK.  Jester's explanation sounds likely, unless you made sure to look at CS:EIP after the jump.  (Although if GDB knew the CPU was in 16-bit mode, it would disassemble `00 00` as `add [bx+si],al`.)

Comment: I set the architecture to i8086, because the 16 bit code. I don't know if I am in protected mode. There is a best option for debugging?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like gdb really bought that idea :) You might want to try bochs built-in debugger, that is a lot better for 16 bit and system stuff.

Comment: I tried to use Bosch with IDA Pro, but is terrible xD there is no stack, and no registers

Comment: Yep, bosch works fine ;)

Comment: x86 QEMU does indeed treat unmapped areas of memory as zero. Typically execution off the end of RAM like this will eventually hit the highest addressable location, at which point the program counter will wrap and you'll start again at address 0 executing your guest code all over again in a confusing way. If your only breakpoint in the debugger was at the instruction after the original CALL, this might look to you as if the call returned, even though in fact it has not.

Comment: Thanks to all, I debugged successfully the bootloader with Bosch and the operating system with gdb ;)